# cordova-plugins-qrscanner failed to build for ios

Tags: ios, swift, qr-code, phonegap

I have a PhoneGap app and I'm using the plugin cordova-plugin-qrscanner

My config.xml file includes:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-qrscanner" source="npm" spec="~3.0.1" />
```

I'm building the app using PhoneGap cloud build (https://build.phonegap.com)

On Android the build it is successful and the app is working with no issues

On iOS I'm receiving an error

```
Check dependencies
The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. Supported values are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.
The “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) build setting must be set to a supported value for targets which use Swift. Supported values are: 3.0, 4.0, 4.2. This setting can be set in the build settings editor.

** ARCHIVE FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
Error: xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/private/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
```

I already tried to add swift support plugin

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" source="npm" spec="~2.0.2" />
```

and indicate the swift version as follows

```
<preference name="swift-version" value="3.0" />
<preference name="UseSwiftLanguageVersion" value="3" />
```

But still, no luck and I can't get it to work

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution
I'm posting here for anyone who has the same

add Plugin

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-qrscanner" source="npm" spec="~3.0.1" />
```

I changed the swift-version to 4.2

```
<preference name="UseSwiftLanguageVersion" value="4" />
<preference name="SwiftVersion" value="4.2" />
```

I added swift-support hook using this line

```
<hook type="after_platform_add" src="plugins/cordova-plugin-qrscanner/scripts/swift-support.js" />
```

and one last fix is inside the iOS 'QRScanner.swift' (Path: src/ios/QRScanner.swift)

change "string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString" to "string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString" in openSettings function. line 470

Comment: Will keep this in mind when I get to the build process. Thanks for providing feedback.